# Unable to retrieve date columns in hive

Tags: database, hadoop, hive

I am finding difficulty when it comes to retrieving date values in hive. My query is

```
create external table test1(DISPLAYSCALE int, CREATED_DATE date, LAST_EDITED_DATE date)

ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.esri.hadoop.hive.serde.JsonSerde' STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'com.esri.json.hadoop.UnenclosedJsonInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat';
```

When I try to use the `select * from test1 limit5` I get this error;

> Failed with exception
>   java.io.IOException:java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.DateWritable cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

As per the json the datatype for CREATED_DATE and CREATED_DATE are esriFieldTypeDate and the values are in this format say 2013-11-20 09:39:25.000001.
So i used the date datatype while creating the table, copied it to HDFS using the unenclosed json and used the select * query to retrieve the columns, but I get the above error. To get the values we are creating the same table with string data type respectively instead of date and we are able to get the values .

Can you suggest a solution for this problem. This question may seem silly but I am pretty new to programming.

Comment: With Spatial-Framework-For-Hadoop v1.2+, use `.....EsriJsonSerDe` and `....UnenclosedEsriJsonInputFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

Date data type supports only format YYYY-­MM-­DD

Timestamps or VARCHAR data type you can be used rather than date data type.

Answer (score 0):

Date data types do not exist in Hive. In fact the dates are treated as strings in Hive. Refer the below post

http://www.folkstalk.com/2011/11/date-functions-in-hive.html

Answer (score 0):

`EsriJsonSerDe` (and `GeoJsonSerDe`) support for DATE and TIMETAMP type columns is [added on Spatial-Framework-for-Hadoop master in git](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/pull/124).

Alternately, you can try using `org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe` or `org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe` (instead of EsriJsonSerDe - and with column type `string` rather than `binary`) together with `UnenclosedEsriJsonInputFormat`.

[disclosure: Spatial-Framework-for-Hadoop collaborator]